# Bpy Set all objects to shade smooth

Tags: python, scripting

Below is my script for setting up my object shading, but I am not able to set the mesh to shade smooth. I would like to do this in the most performant way.

```
import bpy
from math import math
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        
        if obj.type=='MESH':

            obj.data.use_auto_smooth = True  
            obj.data.auto_smooth_angle = radians(180)
            obj.use_smooth = True
            #obj.ops.mesh.faces_shade_smooth()`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to make it work:

```
import bpy
import math

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type=='MESH':
        obj.data.use_auto_smooth = True  
        obj.data.auto_smooth_angle = math.radians(180)
        mesh = obj.data
        for f in mesh.polygons:
            f.use_smooth = True
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: np. glad i was able to help :)